# Regular expression for key value example

Tags: regex

I have the following sample:

```
COL1:  'Data sample1'  null TEST2:  'GLO'  null DATA3:  'value with spaces'  null -->
```

The background of this specific sample is a DELETE operation on a table record, the old and new values are displayed as a result. I am building a custom pattern for ElasticSearch's grok processor, the above sample is part of a log entry. The pattern is(seperated by two spaces each ):

```
KEY1:  oldvalue1  newvalue1  KEY2:  oldvalue2  newvalue2 .....
```

I am looking for an expression to obtain the **oldvalues** and one for obtaining the **newvalues**, including sinqle quotes. It is related to the occurence and I currently have the following expression to start with :

```
\s\s.[^\s\s]+..
```

But this will already not work for the single quote values containing spaces.  Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: which language you are using?

Comment: will the new values be in quotes? or will it be without it?

Comment: `[^\s\s]` probably doesn't do what you hope; see the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) which has a section about common beginner mistakes, including negation. (For what it's worth, `[^\s]` is exactly equivalent, which is usually better written `\S`. Also please [edit] to indicate which regex tool or language you are using, as also explained in the tag info.)

Comment: Hello all, thanks for the quick response. I appreciate it. I am building a custom pattern for Elastic's grok processor, the above sample is part of a log entry. I have added the information in the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `(\w+):\s+('[^']+')\s+('[^']+'|\w+)`

Check out a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/CD59PP/2)

### Explanation

- `(\w+):` - Captures the key (`KEY:`) - assumes it only contains word characters
- `\s+`: Consumes all the whitespace up until the first `'`
- `('[^']+')`: Captures the value inside quotes
- `\s+`: Consumes all the whitespace until the next word
- `('[^']+'|\w+)` - Captures either a value inside quotes or word characters without quotes (like `null`)